# Looking for advice on how to properly dispose of database objects and what cleaning up may be necessary

Tags: c#, ado.net, db2

I am trying to perform two updates to a database table in a single transaction whenever the user "updates" a record. First, I "cancel out" the original record by setting the Cancel date equal to the Effective date. Then, I enter a new record with the values provided. THis is how we record update history.

I am looking for advice on how to properly dispose of database objects and what cleaning up may be necessary. For example, are my "using" blocks reasonable? Can I assume that an implied rollback takes place if a transaction is started but something goes wrong anywhere after the transaction is started?

```
    public void UpdateStateAssessment(Models.StateAssessment stateAssessment)
    {
        string updateSql = @"UPDATE GSAS.ST_ASSMT_REF 
                          SET 
                             CAN_DT       = EFF_DT  
                          WHERE
                               VENDR_ID = @VENDR_ID AND
                               EFF_DT   = @EFF_DT   AND
                               LAST_TS  = @LAST_TS";

        string insertSql = @"INSERT INTO GSAS.ST_ASSMT_REF 
                        (
                         VENDR_ID   
                        ,ST_ASSMT_NM    
                        ,ST_CD  
                        ,EFF_DT 
                        ,CAN_DT 
                        ,LAST_TS    
                        ,LAST_OPER_ID      
                        )
                        VALUES
                        (
                         @VENDR_ID
                        ,@ST_ASSMT_NM
                        ,@ST_CD
                        ,@EFF_DT
                        ,@CAN_DT
                        ,CURRENT TIMESTAMP    
                        ,@LAST_OPER_ID
                        )";

        try
        {
            using (var connection = OpenConnection())
            {
                DB2Transaction sqltransaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

                using (sqltransaction)
                {
                    using (DB2Command cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = updateSql;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Transaction = sqltransaction;
                        cmd.Connection = connection;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new DB2Parameter("@CAN_DT", DB2Type.Date) { Value = stateAssessment.CancelDate.Date });
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new DB2Parameter("@VENDR_ID", DB2Type.Char) { Value = stateAssessment.VendorId });
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new DB2Parameter("@EFF_DT", DB2Type.Date) { Value = stateAssessment.EffectiveDate.Date });
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new DB2Parameter("@LAST_TS", DB2Type.DateTime) { Value = stateAssessment.LastTimestamp });
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    using (DB2Command cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = insertSql;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Transaction = sqltransaction;
                        cmd.Connection = connection;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new DB2Parameter("@ST_ASSMT_NM", DB2Type.Char) { Value = stateAssessment.Name });
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new DB2Parameter("@ST_CD", DB2Type.Char) { Value = stateAssessment.StateCode });
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new DB2Parameter("@CAN_DT", DB2Type.Date) { Value = stateAssessment.CancelDate.Date });
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new DB2Parameter("@LAST_OPER_ID", DB2Type.Char) { Value = stateAssessment.LastOperatorId });
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new DB2Parameter("@VENDR_ID", DB2Type.Char) { Value = stateAssessment.VendorId });
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new DB2Parameter("@EFF_DT", DB2Type.Date) { Value = stateAssessment.EffectiveDate.Date });
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    sqltransaction.Commit();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //Log the error.
            //Any Cleaning up to do?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your disposable objects are all correctly wrapped in a `using` block so they're going to get disposed, even in the even of an exception.

Because the commands are included in the transaction they aren't committed until the transaction is committed. If the first command executes but the second throws an exception then the transaction won't get committed.

The [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/DB2ConnectionClassBeginTransactionMethods.html) says to explicitly roll back the transaction if it's not committed.

```
sqltransaction.Rollback();
```

Comment: Then I need to move the declaration of the sqltransaction object so it is in the outer block and I have to check to see if it is not null before I rollback. Perhaps there is also a way to check to see if the transaction has begun, too before I attempt to roll back...? That's why I was hoping that the using block handled the rollback, too.

Comment: You can create the transaction in the using statement - `using(var sqltransaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))` - like you do with the command. Then within that, place a try/catch. If an exception is thrown, roll back the transaction before it goes out of scope.